# How can I stream from an Azure Function using SignalR and ChannelReader<T>?

Tags: c#, .net, azure, azure-functions, signalr

I'm attempting to stream text responses from a.NET 8 Azure function running in isolated mode to an ASP.NET Core Web App running the Azure signalr javascript client. I'm currently debugging this locally using the Azure signalr emulator.

I'm using the explicit `[SignalRTrigger]` / `[SignalROutput]` bindings on the Azure Function methods, as opposed to using the class-based model.

I initially tried to return an `IAsyncEnumerable<T>` from the function method, however it's not supported by either Newtonsoft.json or System.Text.Json in the context of Azure Functions.

I therefore switched to using `ChannelReader<T>`, however when I attempt to invoke the function, the method doesn't get called when executing the `stream(...)` client method.

Javascript client code:

```
connection
    .stream("streamMessages", message)
     .subscribe({
         next: (chunk) => {
             var r = document.getElementById("response");
             r.textContent = r.textContent + chunk;
         },
         complete: () => {
             console.log("Stream completed");
         },
         error: (err) => {
             console.error(err.toString());
         },
     });
```

Azure Function code:

```
[Function(nameof(StreamMessages))]
public ChannelReader<string> StreamMessages(
    [SignalRTrigger(
        "AIAgentHub", "messages", "streamMessages", new string[] { "message"}, ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")]
            SignalRInvocationContext invocationContext,
    string message, FunctionContext functionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
}
```

Note that the javascript `invoke(...)` method works so it seems there's nothing inherently wrong with setting up the connection, etc. Client code:

```
connection
    .invoke("sendMessage", message)
    .catch(function (err) {
        return console.error(err.toString());
});
```

Azure Function code:

```
[Function(nameof(SendMessage))]
[SignalROutput(HubName = "AIAgentHub", ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")]
public async Task<SignalRMessageAction> SendMessage(
    [SignalRTrigger(
        "AIAgentHub", "messages", "sendMessage", new string[] { "message"}, ConnectionStringSetting = "AzureSignalRConnectionString")]
            SignalRInvocationContext invocationContext,
    string message, FunctionContext functionContext, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    ...
}
```

Is this something that only works with the class-based implementation or inside a Web API instead of an Azure function?

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks,
Richard

Comment: I've got the same question. I'm really struggling converting some of our legacy applications to .NET8 when using SignalR. It seems the documentation available hasn't caught up with recent changes. Have you had any luck?

Comment: My issue was specific to the use of Azure Functions - in the end I gave up and just used a WebAPI instead which worked as expected.  

If you give more specific details about the problem you're having, someone might be able to help out.  

IMHO that's often the way with Microsoft documentation - features are developed and updated so rapidly that there's lots of conflicting (often out-of-date) official documentation.